# Problems with Cloudflare 403 and Python

Tags: python, http, cloudflare, http-status-code-403, bypass

I've been trying to make a code auto redeemer for a site. There’s a problem every time I send a request to the website the. The issue is a 403 error which means I haven't passed the right fooling methods, like headers, cookies, and CF.

But I have, so I'm lost. I've tried everything. The problem is 100% Cloudflare having a strange verification, and I can't find a way to bypass it. I've passed authentication headers with correct cookies as well. I've tried with the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. And with cloudscrape and [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)) 4.

The site is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'
}
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
r = scraper.get('https://rblxwild.com/api/promo-code/redeem-code', headers=headers)
print(r) > 403
```

How can I bypass the Cloudflare protection methods?

Comment: What is a *"fooling method"*? Do you mean *"tooling method"* (whatever that is)?

Comment: What is "CF"? [Cloudflare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudflare)? [ColdFusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ColdFusion)? Something else?